# remove route listing in playframework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Playframework displays a whole list of all available routes if you call a wrong route. that looks like that:

[image]

Is there a way to deactivate this listing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Play provides ErrorHandler, Where you can handler server and client side error. To avoid this you can give customer HTML "page not found" page inside onClientError, Have a look at the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaErrorHandling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this only in the development mode, it's for easy debugging.

In the production mode, the list would be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Play provides the default [error handling mechanism](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaErrorHandling)

You can override the [onClientError](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/http/HttpErrorHandler.html)

```
   override def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String): Future[Result] =
    statusCode match {

      case NOT_FOUND =>
        Future.successful {
          NotFound(Json.obj("error" -> s"Resource  ${request.uri} is invalid"))//or whatever error message you want.
        }
    }
```